Why does return type covariance (C#9) not work on interfaces?
Covariance allows to define a new type in an overridden method of a base class as long as the newly returned type is an inherited type of the original, e.g.
internal class Car { }

internal class Bmw : Car { }

internal class CarManager
{
    public virtual Car CreateCar()
        => new();
}

internal class BmwManager : CarManager
{
    public override Bmw CreateCar()
        => new();
}

But when it try to interface it like this:
internal class CarManager : ICarManager
{
    public virtual Car CreateCar()
        => new();
}

internal class BmwManager : CarManager, IBmwManager
{
    public override Bmw CreateCar()
        => new();
}

internal interface ICarManager
{
    Car CreateCar();
}

internal interface IBmwManager : ICarManager
{
    Bmw CreateCar(); //hide warning comes here
}

I get a compiler warning that IBmwManager.CreateCar() hides ICarManager.CreateCar() and I'm supposed to use the new keyword here. Hiding is what you always had to do pre-covariance if you wanted to do something like this, even on classlevel. But now it is working on a class level but not interface level, why?
